# Error - Calling Oracle function from Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, function

I am trying to call a oracle function that takes one varchar input argument and returns a varchar. But it throws the following error. I have tried changing the type from varchar to nvarchar in Java but it did not help.

```
 java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_DATA_TEST'
```

PLSQL function definition

```
 create or replace FUNCTION     Get_Data_test (p_acct callid)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
  AS
```

Java function:

```
        String call = "{ ? = call Get_Data_test(?)}";
        CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(call);
        cstmt.setQueryTimeout(1800);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.setString(2, "12345678");
        cstmt.executeQuery();
        name = cstmt.getString(1);
        System.out.println("hello: "+name);
```

Answer (score 2):

`cstmt.setString(2, "12345678")` is giving it impression that there are two in parameters. So change that to `cstmt.setString(1, "12345678")`.

Also, it should come prior to `cstmt.registerOutParameter`, as we need to set input parameter first and then outparam. Check a tutorial on same.

**EDIT** - Looks like a problem with your input parameter type (p_acct callid). In function, check what is it's type. Chosse a type here in java accordingly.

Comment: I changed the order but still I get the same error. <br/> String call = "{ ? = call Get_Cdr_Data_test(?)}";
            CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(call);
            cstmt.setQueryTimeout(1800);
            cstmt.setString(1, "477505655017033242764");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

Comment: see - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96659/04_call.htm#15166 as count is same (1) for input and output - the issue will be most probably with TYPE of argument (I think of input type).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
String sequenceQuery;

sequenceQuery = "{call Get_Data_test(?,?)}";  // where ?'s are the parameters

connection = DataSourceLocator.getInstance().getDataSource().getConnection();
callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(sequenceQuery);

callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

callableStatement.setString(2,"12345678");

callableStatement.execute();
```